# weird behavior when initializing static member of a static class

Tags: c#, concurrency, static, locking, initialization

I have problem with the initialization of the static member of a static class. As far as I know, it will be initialized one time only, so I lock this variable when I do fooList.Add(...) in concurrency, to ensure this operation is thread safe:

```
internal static class ObjectA
{
    private static object _lockAdd = new object();

    public void functionA()
    {
       lock (_lockAdd)
       {...
```

I encountered some weird situations, so I decided to write the hashcode of _lockAdd by log4net, and to my surprise this is what I observed:

【INFO】【2012-04-20 15:26:44,080】【thread12】
 _lockAdd's hashcode (51755728)...

【INFO】【2012-04-20 15:26:58,624】【thread16】
 _lockAdd's hashcode (31071611)...

As you see, the two '_lockAdd ' addresses are different, why is it, or is my understanding of static members wrong ? And how should i do to ensure thread safety when the operation is in a static class?

sorry for the fake code's error, this is my actual code:

```
internal static class UtilExtension
{               
    private static object _lockAdd = new object(); //initial twice ? why?

    public static void DoAdd(this Type entityType)
    {            
        if (!Pools.Has(entityType))
        {
            lock (_lockAdd) 
            {
                if (!Pools.Has(entityType)) //insure operation below is thread safe
                {
                    // i find something wrong in concurrency,so i log the _lockAdd's hashcode,
                    // and then i found it's hashcode is different( in my opinion, it means not the same variables )
                    LogUtil.Info(_lockAdd.GetHashCode().ToString());

                    //... do fooList.Add(...)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you having any of this?!

Comment: Please post your actual code. What you have provided would not compile (you have a static class with a non static member function). The behavior you're seeing seems like you've applied the ThreadStatic attribute to your static lock object.

Comment: Are there multiple AppDomains involved?

Comment: What do you mean by hashcode for that member? How exactly do you get it?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, no ,just one domain , and i start N Threads to test the lock issue

Comment: @ Maciej Dopieralski, i thought static member alwasy has one memory address, no matter how many threads use it.so i write the hashcode to improve my assumption, but it's wrong

Comment: @yoyo: That's *normally* the case, but not when you use `[ThreadStatic]`. If you could edit your post again to make it a short but *complete* program which demonstrates this behaviour, that would help...

Answer (score 1):

For an object only used for `lock`ing, use `readonly`:

```
private static readonly object _lockAdd = new object();
```

If the object was getting overwritten somehow, you'll most probably get different results from either the compiler or runtime next time you start the application.

Comment: and i am still confused about the static member,how could it initialize twice,even without add readonly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i make it complicated, the truth is that,the static member is thread unsafe always。So when we use a static member(_lockAdd) as a lock target, we should add readonly to insure the _lockAdd is initilize only once.